# How to embed an iframe with custom data and size?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've got a custom **JS snippet that clients may install on their websites**. On request, that snippet can fetch some data from an external server and then embed an IFrame to the website's dom to render the output.

I'm having some issues with

1. properly passing the information down to the IFrame (cross-origin access). To do so, I have:

```
  // JS snippet, part that sets the iframe
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.style.position = "fixed";
  iframe.src = "someUrlContaining my HTML + JS"
  iframe.style ...

  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  // Once receive "readyToReceive" message => iframe.contentWindow?.postMessage(dataToRender)

 --------------------------------

  // Iframe JS tells the SDK it's ready to receive and waits for payload to render
  window?.top?.postMessage("readyToReceive", "*") // telling the Snippet that it was appended
  window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {if data => renderData(data)}, false);
```

2. correctly setting the size of the Iframe once it renders - the size is dynamic depended on the content and I want the iframe to be only as big as required.

This feels very clunky to me. I assume I'm doing something wrong. What would be a simple way to pass data up/down from the JS Snippet (I've got ownership of it) down to the Iframe (again, I've got ownership of that)?

Further, what would be a simple way of sizing the IFrame dynamically depending on what the iframe renders (the iframe renders stuff via a bunch of `document.AppendChild()`)?

Comment: Why not make your data available via an AJAX call and let the clients decide where and how big to render it?

Comment: Hey @ScottMarcus So both the Snippet and IFrame make use of the data. I fetch it initially in the snippet, do some processing and finally create the IFrame where I want to pass it down too (instead of fetching it twice). Separately, the Iframe contains the render logic so till it renders (basically json -> components) I don't know the exact dimensions